# Python - reading hyperlink information?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

i try to read a hyperlink-information from an excel-sheet using the following code:

```
import os
import sys
import xlwings as xw

path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))  
fn = os.path.join(path, "inp.xlsx")    
wb = xw.Book (fn)
ws1 = wb.sheets["MainOverview"] 
val =  ws1["H18"].value
inpLink = ws1["H18"].hyperlink
print(f"{val}: {inpLink}")
val =  ws1["I18"].value
inpLink = ws1["I18"].hyperlink
print(f"{val}: {inpLink}")
```

In cell H18 there is a link to another place / worksheet in the document - see attached the information it shows when hoovering ofer the link in the cell:

[image]

And in the cell I18 i have a link to a website - attached the hoovering info:

[image]

But when i run the program i only get this output:

```
View Findings: 
Google: https://www.google.com/
```

So i only get the link-information for the website-link but not to the file-link information from cell H18.

How is it possible to get the full file link (file:///C:\DEV...) from the cell H18?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to dig a little deeper to get the Address and SubAddress from the api.
If the hyperlink is internal like it appears H18 is, then the Address will be blank and the SubAdress will only hold the internal details: Sheet name and cell.
So H18 would only return;
`DeadLogic!A1`
The path of the link would obviously be the path to the workbook you opened.

I18 being an external link should return a value in the Address field only, that being;
`https://www.google.com/`

```
...
ws1 = wb.sheets["MainOverview"] 

print(f"H18: {ws1['H18'].value}")
for lnk in ws1['H18'].api.Hyperlinks:
    print(f"Addr: {lnk.Address}")
    print(f"Subaddr: {lnk.SubAddress}\n")

print(f"I18: {ws1['I18'].value}")
for lnk in ws1['I18'].api.Hyperlinks:
    print(f"Addr: {lnk.Address}")
    print(f"Subaddr: {lnk.SubAddress}")
```

The above code example would show;

```
H18: View Findings
Addr: 
Subaddr: DeadLogic!A1

I18: Google
Addr: https://www.google.com/
Subaddr:
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - works great!
Only minor additonal question probably - tried to do this is one line with  `ws1['I18'].api._inner.Hyperlinks.SubAddress` but get an error
Do you know why this is not working in one line without the for-loop?

Comment: You need the 'Hyperlink' item but I dont see it in the attributes so could  only access using for loop. btw you should be able to drop the `_inner` and just use `.api.Hyperlinks`. I updated the example